# White border around image in CSS, Why is this appearing and how do I get rid of it?

Tags: css

I have been playing around with some images in CSS and have been attempting to use `border: none;` in the styling to get rid of the white boxes surrounding my images as shown here: [image]

Have you guys ever encountered this? Slash am I forgetting a style to manipulate.. I've used firebug to go over the CSS and there is no direct white border put around the images.

Comment: Can you provide us some sample HTML or a link to where we can view this problem?

Comment: Try this:

img{border:0;}

You can also limitate the scope and only remove border on some images by doing so:

.myClass img{border:0;}

More information about the border css property can by found here.

Edit: Changed border from 0px to 0. As explained in comments, px is redundant for a unit of 0

Comment: Do the images themselves have that border? (it can be hard to tell in an image editor)

Comment: Please provide a fiddler. Should be an easy thing.

Comment: are you wrapping those images with another tag? have you tried to apply border="0" as an attribute on the img tag itself?

Comment: As most of you have stated, I went ahead and played with border:0 in the correct location and found the problem, thanks guys!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
img{border:0;}
```

if you want inside just particular class scope

```
.yourClass img{border:0;}
```

This will also work `img{border:none, outline: none;}`

Comment: It worked, border:0; in the correct location solved my problem. Thanks Ankur! I was wondering what the difference is exactly between border:0; vs border: none; http://i.imgur.com/eGgu9Vm.jpg

Comment: `border: 0; will set border-width: 0; while border: none; will set border-style: none;` you are welcome :)  
may be you can accept the answer now if it worked